# Boxing labels across branches in LaTeX trees

Tags: qtree

I have inserted a tree diagram in a LaTeX document which I have drawn using the `qtree` package:

```
...
\usepackage[noload]{qtree}
...
\begin{document}
...
\Tree [.{A} [.{B} {C} {D} ] [.{B'} {D'} ] ]
...
\end{document}
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image]

So far, so good.

What I would need to do now is wrap the final nodes of the tree into (labeled) boxes in a way that cuts across the syntactic branching of the tree.

To give you an idea, this is a very rough sketch of what I would like to achieve (where *a* and *b* stand for the box labels):

[image]

I understand that this might be unattainable with `qtree` since the `!qframesubtree` only allows you to put boxes around complete subtrees.

Any suggestions as to how to get around the problem?

Comment: This is really best done with one of the TikZ based tree drawing packages. `qtree` is really old now. I would recommend `forest` which can do this trivially.

Comment: I am not sure how this coud be achieved using `forest` either, since `forest` seems to also require specifying the child nodes of the current subtree to be boxed, not those of other subtrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `forest` solution.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{child frame/.style={tikz={\node () [rectangle, red,draw, fit=#1,inner sep = 0pt] {};}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[A [B [C,name=C,child frame={(C),label=below:a} ] [D,name=D ] ] [B',child frame={(D)(D1),label=right:b} [D',name=D1 ] ]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @poxx If you remove the `red` from my style description, you can add your own colour or `dashed` etc. to the `child frame={ ... }` style on any individual node. As with all TikZ things, if you're using things repeatedly, it makes sense to make a style for it. E.g. `\tikzset{rd/.style={red,dashed,thick}` and then add `rd` to the `child frame` options. Because these are passed to `tikz` not`forest` they are set using `tikzset` not `forestset`.

Comment: (+1) I'd recommend `tikz+` so that `child frame` could be used more than once or in combination with some other wanted effect. But I guess this isn't terribly likely.

Comment: @cfr So e.g. if D itself had a `tikz=` option, this would simply add to it?  I've never needed this in practice, but I see the point.  So much to learn about `forest`.

Comment: In that case, it would depend on the order. If the `tikz` is processed first, the `tikz+` would add to it. If the `tikz+` is processed first, the `tikz` would zap it. `tikz` sets it. `tikz+` adds to whatever is there, if anything. I have sometimes needed this and, in earlier versions, you could only manage 2 lots (with `tikz` and `afterthought`). I haven't needed `afterthought` in a long time!

Comment: It is especially useful in the case of the root node, as you might want to set multiple `tikz` fragments from there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of [Alan Munn's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383043/), using `fit to`. The first tree uses named nodes. The second doesn't bother.

```
% addaswyd o ateb Alan Munn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383043/
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{
  child frame/.style={
    tikz+={
      \node [draw=blue, fit to={#1}, inner sep=0pt] {};
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [A [B [C, name=C, child frame={name=C}, label=below:a ] [D, name=D ] ] [B', child frame={{name=D, name=D1}}, [D', name=D1, label=right:b ] ]]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  [A [B [C, child frame={c}, label=below:a ] [D ] ] [B' [D', child frame={c,fake={us},l}, label=right:b ] ]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Oh, and mine are blue ...

[image: Forest trees with boxes]