# Unevenly aligned nodes in forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

This should be a cakewalk but for some reason I can't find the key to it.

Following [Alan Munn's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383040/boxing-labels-across-branches-in-latex-trees/383043?noredirect=1#comment947820_383043), I have recently switched from `qtree` to `forest` for tree diagrams. Using the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}
%...
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
%...
\begin{document}
%...
\begin{forest}
[A [B [C ] [D ] [E,edge=dotted ] ] [F [G ] ] ]
\end{forest}
%...
\end{document}
```

the following tree obtains:

[image]

How can I set a specific (shorter) length for the dotted line? I would like for node E to be positioned above the level of C, D, and G.

As the dotted line suggests, E is only remotely connected with what the tree represents, and I don't want it to be on the same level of the other bottom nodes.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead wrap the fragments in a minimal compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: Edited into a fully compilable MWE.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the `l` parameter for a single node. It can lead to some funny results if you make the value too small, but for this purpose it seems to work.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}
%...
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
%...
\begin{document}
%...
\begin{forest}
[A [B [C ] [D ] [E,edge=dotted,l=.75cm ] ] [F [G ] ] ]
\end{forest}
%...
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This works, thanks. I also applied the same `tier` to C, D, and G to make E the only unaligned node.

Comment: (+1) `l'=.75cm` would be faster.

Comment: @cfr `l'` is an undocumented feature... (appears nowhere in the docs that I can see.)

Comment: Page 36. It is a standard feature for all dimension options/registers. (Also integers etc.)

Comment: >> The evaluation of pgfmath can be quite slow. There are two tricks to speed things up if the pgfmath expression is simple, i.e. just a TEX dimen:
1. pgfmath evaluation of simple values can be sped up by prepending + to the value [2, §62.1];
2. use the key option’=value to invoke a normal TEX assignment.
The two above-mentioned speed-up tricks work for the augmented assignments as well. The keys for the second, TEX-only trick are: ’+, ’-, ’*, ’: — note that for the latter two, the value should be an integer.

Comment: @cfr Thanks. I was looking specifically for `l'`, since other similar keys show up in the index.

Comment: Well, and you're right. `l'` is not specifically documented. It just isn't an undocumented feature, either. I have an advantage here: many of the avoid-pgfmath features were given a user interface when Sašo tried to figure out how `prooftrees` could be made faster and realised I was already using most of the (few) tricks available at the time, so provided some more. So we've been through `prooftrees` code trying to eliminate every use of `pgfmath` we could ... :-). Or, rather, I've followed Sašo through it ....

Answer (score 3):

Forest also allows you to manually adjust the position of nodes before the tree is drawn (see chapter workflow, p.24 in forest manual). Note that `x-=3` is augmented assignment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}
%...
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
%...
\begin{document}
%...
\begin{forest}
[A [B [C ] [D ] [E,edge=dotted, before drawing tree={x-=3mm, y+=3mm} ]
 ] [F [G ] ] ]
\end{forest}
%...
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

You can also change the `inner ysep` to adjust the distance between the dotted line and the node content.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}
%...
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
%...
\begin{document}
%...
\begin{forest}
[A [B [C ] [D ] [E,edge=dotted, inner ysep=1pt, before drawing tree={x-=2mm, y+=2mm} ]
 ] [F [G ] ] ]
\end{forest}
%...
\end{document}
```

[image]